# Morris graph is only shown when I resize the window

Tags: angularjs, morris.js

I'm using Morris graph and I'm facing the issue that the graph is not shown, it's only shown when I resize the window like zoom in or out.

Code is given below:

HTML page

```html
         <div class="content" ng-controller="SuperUserController">
    
          <LineChart xkey="xkey" ykeys="ykeys" labels="labels"  ng-show="lineChart"  ></LineChart>
        <i class="fa fa-area-chart" ng-click="graphSet(1)"></i>
       
     </div
```

Angular js file

```js
        $scope.graph=true;
        $scope.lineChart = false;
    
        $scope.xkey = 'xAxis';
        $scope.ykeys = ['yAxis'];
        $scope.labels = ['unit'];
        $scope.myModel = [];
    
        $scope.graphSet=function($id) {
            $scope.deviceId=$id;
            dataFactory.httpRequest('/graph/yesterday/' + $id).then(function (data) {
                if (Object.keys(data).length !== 0) {
                    $scope.graph = true;
                    $scope.lineChart = true;
    
                    $scope.myModel = data;
            }
                
        });
    
        }
    myapp.directive('linechart',function(){ //directive name must be in small letters
    
        return {
            // required to make it work as an element
            restrict: 'E',
            template: '<div></div>',
            replace: true,
            link:function($scope,element,attrs)
            {
    
                var data = $scope[attrs.data],
                    xkey = $scope[attrs.xkey],
                    ykeys = $scope[attrs.ykeys],
                    labels = $scope[attrs.labels];
                $scope.$watch("myModel", function (newValue) {
                    data = newValue;
                    console.log(newValue);
    
                    Linechart.setData(newValue);
    
                });
                config = {
                    element: element,//element means id #
                    data: data,
                    xkey: xkey,
                    ykeys: ykeys,
    
                    labels: labels,
                    parseTime: false,
                    pointFillColors: ['#D58665'],
                    lineColors: ['#0b62a4'],
                    smooth: true,
                    hideHover: 'auto',
                    pointSize: 4,
                    axes: true,
                    resize: true,
                    fillOpacity: 1.0,
                    grid: true,
    
                }
    
    
                    Linechart = Morris.Line(config);
    
    
    
            }
        }
    
    
    })
```

When I click on the icon the LineChart, element is shown but graph is not shown. Graph is only shown when I resize the window.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem

use ng-if="lineChart" instead of ng-show="lineChart"

Comment: when i use ng-if,it show half graph and when zoom in or out then show full graph.

Comment: if you are loading graph based on button click event..try clearing older graph first..

Comment: So how can clean older graph?

Comment: you need to check morris options for clearing graph - In my case graph is rendered inside div by id..so cleared graph by passing null value to div's innerhtml..

Answer (score 0):

I do this, and it works.

```
let bar = Morris.Bar({...});
setTimeout(function () {
    let element_svg = document.querySelector("#id svg");
    element_svg.style.setProperty("width", "100%");
    bar.redraw();
}, 200);
```

using setTimeout to make sure that svg has been rendered